# Haikou, China > Hong Kong > Doha, do I need to recheck luggage?

Tags: luggage, short-connections, qatar-airways, hkg, cathay-dragon

Im flying from Haikou to Denmark tomorrow. I would like to know if I have to pick up my luggage and check in all over in Hong Kong, as I will have very little time in HK.

Haikou > HK is with Dragonair.
From there it's Qatar Airways.

Comment: Is this one ticket or two?

Answer (score 2):

Dragonair is not a [codeshare partner with Qatar Airways](http://www.qatarairways.com/kw/en/codeshare-partners.page), therefore you will likely be flying on two separate tickets.

One is Haikou - Hong Kong, then the other separate ticket from Hong Kong to Denmark, via Doha on Qatar Airways.

As these are separate journeys, you will have to collect your luggage; however [qatar airways does not block other airlines from doing interline bookings](http://support.qatarairways.com/hc/en-us/articles/206461458-Which-partner-airlines-do-you-support-in-your-interline-bookings-) which means that **it might be possible** for Dragonair to check your luggage with Qatar Airways.

You just have to ask when you check-in for your flight.

Comment: So with only 1h 20min in HK, at best, ill most likely not make it in time. Am I on my own then and have to pay for new tickets, or will some other flights be arranged for me instead?

Comment: Well your situation would be just as if you arrived late at the airport; so the costs associated with rebooking would be based on the fare rules of your ticket.

Comment: On matrix I can find flights from HAK to DOH via HKG with HAK-HKG operated by dragonair and HKG-DOH by QR on one QR ticket

Comment: @Daniel: this all depends if this one booking or two separate bookings. Please answer the question in the comment to your original post